# For each split on vbNewLine doesn't work

Tags: vb.net

I'm coding a little program that'll check different login credentials against my own server the problem is basically that I have a for each right here:

```
 For Each strLine1 As String In TextBox2.Text.Split(vbNewLine)
        For Each strLine2 As String In TextBox3.Text.Split(vbNewLine)
            TextBox4.Text = strLine1 + strLine2
            log(strLine1, strLine2)
        Next
    Next
```

When I use log(username, password) that works perfectly and when I put only 1 string in each textbox and they're correct it works, but as soon as I add other values in the textbox it doesn't work.

Like this:

```
USERNAME          PASSWORD
Working           WORKING
```

^ Works

But when I use something like this

```
USERNAME              PASSWORD
Not working           Not working
Not working           Working
Working               Not working
```

^That doesn't work... 
It's extremely frusterating and I've tested to add both values in a multi line textbox too see if the vbNewLine aka \n is still there but it isn't.

I know this explanation is really hard to understand but think of it as a bruteforcer/cracker of some kind that's going through a username password list. I'm only doing this for test purposes.

Any help is extremely appreciated!

Comment: The problem with your question is that you don't explain what is not working.

Comment: I wrote what didn't work, if you add multiple credentials that it needs to go through it won't work.

Comment: Try using `.Text.Split({vbNewLine}, StringSplitOptions.None)` instead and see if that helps (edited since vbNewLine or vbCrLf should work the same).

Comment: Yeah that didn't work It's extremely frustrating.. If someone could be willing to help me over join.me or something I can award that person with 3 goat simulator cd-keys!

Comment: A multiline textbox has a property called [Lines](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.textboxbase.lines(v=vs.110).aspx), so you don't really need to split anything. Try to use this property and explain what is the final content of TextBox4.Text after the end of the loop

Comment: FYI, I believe that `vbNewLine` is `\r\n`, not just `\n`, i.e. it's the same as `vbCrLf`.  You could try splitting on `vbLf` and/or `vbCr` - maybe `.Split({vbCr, vbLf}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)` would work.

Comment: For each line in TextBox2 you are looking at *every* line in TextBox3. Is that what you intend? Also, `TextBox4.Text = strLine1 + strLine2` replaces the .Text of TextBox4; maybe you want `.AppendText` instead. Oh, and the text concatenation operator in VB.Net is `&`, not `+`.